# Confused about the timing of event updates and consumption in Bevy

Tags: rust, bevy

I am trying the following code to learn about the `Event` in the Bevy engine:

```
use bevy::prelude::*;

use std::io::{self, BufRead};
use std::time::Duration;

fn runner(mut app: App) {
    let stdin = io::stdin();
    for line in stdin.lock().lines() {
        if let Err(err) = line {
            println!("read err: {:#}", err);
            break;
        }
        match line.unwrap().as_str() {
            "" => {
                app.update();
            }
            "u" => {
                println!("UNPAUSE: resuming virtual clock");
                app.world.resource_mut::<Time<Virtual>>().unpause();
            }
            _ => {
                println!("QUITTING!");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

fn print_real_time(time: Res<Time<Real>>) {
    println!(
        "PreUpdate: this is real time clock, delta is {:?} and elapsed is {:?}",
        time.delta(),
        time.elapsed()
    );
}

fn print_fixed_time(time: Res<Time>) {
    println!(
        "FixedUpdate: this is generic time clock inside fixed, delta is {:?} and elapsed is {:?}",
        time.delta(),
        time.elapsed()
    );
}

fn print_time(time: Res<Time>) {
    println!(
        "Update: this is generic time clock, delta is {:?} and elapsed is {:?}",
        time.delta(),
        time.elapsed()
    );
}

fn main() {
    App::new()
        .add_plugins(MinimalPlugins)
        .insert_resource(Time::<Virtual>::from_max_delta(Duration::from_secs(5)))
        .insert_resource(Time::<Fixed>::from_duration(Duration::from_secs(1)))
        .insert_resource(Counter(0))
        .add_event::<MyEvent>()
        .add_systems(PreUpdate, print_real_time)
        .add_systems(FixedUpdate, (
            print_fixed_time,
            send_event,
            read_event
        ).chain())
        .add_systems(Update, print_time)
        .set_runner(runner)
        .run();
}

#[derive(Event, Default)]
struct MyEvent;

#[derive(Resource)]
struct Counter(i32);

fn send_event(mut events: EventWriter<MyEvent>, mut counter: ResMut<Counter>) {
    if counter.0 == 0 {
        counter.0 = 1;
        events.send_default();
    }
}

fn read_event(events: EventReader<MyEvent>) {
    println!("events.len: {:?}", events.len());
}
```

According to my current understanding, the old event queue should be cleared after each call to `app.update()`. However, when I run the code, I get the following output.

```
u
UNPAUSE: resuming virtual clock

PreUpdate: this is real time clock, delta is 0ns and elapsed is 0ns
Update: this is generic time clock, delta is 0ns and elapsed is 0ns

PreUpdate: this is real time clock, delta is 339.5194ms and elapsed is 339.5194ms
Update: this is generic time clock, delta is 339.5194ms and elapsed is 339.5194ms

PreUpdate: this is real time clock, delta is 284.6968ms and elapsed is 624.2162ms        
Update: this is generic time clock, delta is 284.6968ms and elapsed is 624.2162ms        

PreUpdate: this is real time clock, delta is 259.5447ms and elapsed is 883.7609ms        
Update: this is generic time clock, delta is 259.5447ms and elapsed is 883.7609ms        

PreUpdate: this is real time clock, delta is 331.6477ms and elapsed is 1.2154086s        
FixedUpdate: this is generic time clock inside fixed, delta is 1s and elapsed is 1s      
events.len: 1
Update: this is generic time clock, delta is 331.6477ms and elapsed is 1.2154086s        

PreUpdate: this is real time clock, delta is 280.329ms and elapsed is 1.4957376s
Update: this is generic time clock, delta is 280.329ms and elapsed is 1.4957376s

PreUpdate: this is real time clock, delta is 304.713ms and elapsed is 1.8004506s
Update: this is generic time clock, delta is 304.713ms and elapsed is 1.8004506s

PreUpdate: this is real time clock, delta is 287.542ms and elapsed is 2.0879926s
FixedUpdate: this is generic time clock inside fixed, delta is 1s and elapsed is 2s      
events.len: 1
Update: this is generic time clock, delta is 287.542ms and elapsed is 2.0879926s

PreUpdate: this is real time clock, delta is 268.0542ms and elapsed is 2.3560468s        
Update: this is generic time clock, delta is 268.0542ms and elapsed is 2.3560468s        

PreUpdate: this is real time clock, delta is 279.7958ms and elapsed is 2.6358426s        
Update: this is generic time clock, delta is 279.7958ms and elapsed is 2.6358426s        

PreUpdate: this is real time clock, delta is 287.9875ms and elapsed is 2.9238301s        
Update: this is generic time clock, delta is 287.9875ms and elapsed is 2.9238301s        

PreUpdate: this is real time clock, delta is 359.947ms and elapsed is 3.2837771s
FixedUpdate: this is generic time clock inside fixed, delta is 1s and elapsed is 3s      
events.len: 0
Update: this is generic time clock, delta is 359.947ms and elapsed is 3.2837771s   
quit
QUITTING!
```

There are two `Update`s between the first and second `FixedUpdate`, yet this does not clear the event queue. Instead, it is after the second `FixedUpdate` that the event queue is cleared.

On the other hand, if I don't trigger `Update` so frequently, everything appears to be normal, as shown below:

```
u
UNPAUSE: resuming virtual clock

PreUpdate: this is real time clock, delta is 0ns and elapsed is 0ns
Update: this is generic time clock, delta is 0ns and elapsed is 0ns

PreUpdate: this is real time clock, delta is 4.3637156s and elapsed is 4.3637156s
FixedUpdate: this is generic time clock inside fixed, delta is 1s and elapsed is 1s
events.len: 1
FixedUpdate: this is generic time clock inside fixed, delta is 1s and elapsed is 2s      
events.len: 1
FixedUpdate: this is generic time clock inside fixed, delta is 1s and elapsed is 3s      
events.len: 1
FixedUpdate: this is generic time clock inside fixed, delta is 1s and elapsed is 4s      
events.len: 1
Update: this is generic time clock, delta is 4.3637156s and elapsed is 4.3637156s        

PreUpdate: this is real time clock, delta is 1.3086969s and elapsed is 5.6724125s        
FixedUpdate: this is generic time clock inside fixed, delta is 1s and elapsed is 5s      
events.len: 1
Update: this is generic time clock, delta is 1.3086969s and elapsed is 5.6724125s        

PreUpdate: this is real time clock, delta is 998.9384ms and elapsed is 6.6713509s        
FixedUpdate: this is generic time clock inside fixed, delta is 1s and elapsed is 6s      
events.len: 0
Update: this is generic time clock, delta is 998.9384ms and elapsed is 6.6713509s        
quit
QUITTING!
```

The event queue is cleared after the second `Update`.

Hope someone could shed some light on this for me.

Answer (score 0):

I post the same question [on gitbub](https://github.com/bevyengine/bevy/discussions/12362) and have got the answer.

For short, this is not the final form of the event system but just a stopgap. Only use the event system when you are certain to the behaviour.

Comment: The actual response you got from your question - *"Events are buffered until both `FixedUpdate` and `Update` run twice, to give the chance to see them to all systems."* - looks more crucial than simply knowing it is subject to change. If you are using bevy *now*, this is what you need to know.